# What category of adjectives is this? i.e. adjectives entirely unlike their nouns

Tags: adjectives, category

Consider the noun "Jupiter", either the Roman god or the giant gaseous planet in our Solar System.

The adjective is "jovian", entirely unrelated.

Is this a distinct class of adjectives? I suspect there are many more examples.

EDIT: Is it possible that "Jupiter" does not have an adjective? "Jupiterian"?

In most studies for astrophysics I've seen, the go-to adjective is "Jovian"....

Comment: The Roman god Jupiter was also called Jove, so the adjective is highly related to the noun.  The term's "happy" meaning is a result of the planet's supposed astrological influence.

Comment: The noun and adjective may have different etymologies. An adjective is not necessarily derived from the noun. Good question, though.

Comment: _Jupiter_ and _Jove_ have the same etymology. The irregularity was already present in Latin; the _Ju-_ part of _Jupiter_ is the same as the _Jov_ part of _Jovis, Jovem,_ etc. The -_piter_, present only on the nominative case form, just means 'father'. These are all from the same root as _Zeus_ and other gods,  [PIE root **dei-*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/dei.pdf). There's no special name for borrowed names that have irregular parts, btw.

Comment: The statement 'Consider the noun N. The adjective is A, entirely [etymologically] unrelated.' does not make sense. Either it is incorrect (as here), or it should read  'Consider the noun N. There is an adjective A, entirely unrelated etymologically, meaning 'of, pertaining to, like, in some way associated with ... N.' '_The_ adjective' begs the question.

Comment: The word Jovian ultimately derives from *dyeus*, "god", whence *Deus*, *Zeus*, *Dios* (in, e.g. Spanish), etc. the key thing is *so does* Jupiter, which is a classic Latin compound of *dyeus* + *peter* (god + father).

Comment: @DanBron By Jove! You're right!

Comment: You can find a lot of these with animal adjectives: horse/equine, pig/porcine, bear/ursine, dog/canine, cat/feline, monkey/simian, lion/leonine, wolf/lupine, mouse/murine, whale/cetacean, squirrel/sciurine, hedgehog/erinaceous ... basically, nearly all animals known to the Romans (so rats get rat-like, because Romans used the same word for rats and mice, and skunks, being New World creatures, don't seem to have their own adjective—unless it's skunk-like). This is clearly a finite list, but it is still fairly long

Comment: Just because the adjective is not derived from the noun but from one of its synonyms or closely related names.  *Jovian* is the adjective derived from *Jove,* rather than *Jupiter.* https://www.etymonline.com/word/jovian As for "What category," Tony has answered it.

Comment: BTW, we are expected to do some background research before posting a question.

Comment: @Kris Feel free to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called **collateral adjectives**. You can read about them on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collateral_adjective) and check out a list of them on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_collateral_adjectives).